# How to check open shells on a container?

Tags: docker, shell

How could I check if I have currently running interactive shells on a container, like for instance opened with:

`docker exec -it mycontainer sh`

Is there a way to retrieve this information ?

Answer (score 0):

You can exec to `container` and use command below

```
ls /dev/pts/ | wc -l | awk '{print $1-1}'
```

For instance

[image]

Comment: The hostname is going to be the same as the container ID, right? How does this help you figure out if there are shells running?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer if you still need it.

Comment: Not my question. :) But that is a much better answer.